# How does a programming language translator work?

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction

I am curious as how cross-compilers such as Pyjamas work. Do they simply have a list keywords and line by line replacing each word with the translated code? I want to understand.

I apologize for my ignorance, I am just curious.

Comment: Did you try reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)

Comment: Yes, I have haha. I figured they worked the same way, but I just thought I would ask...

Comment: From what I've seen, Pyjamas is a cross-compiler, not an interpreter.  The process is pretty different.

Comment: @templatetypedef I didn't know it was a compiler, but the common approach is similar with respect to semantics, and a fair number of interpreters are using compilers under the hood to translate to (e.g.,) virtual machine code or JIT compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one universal answer that always works, but typically a language-to-language translator works in much the same way that a compiler does - it reads in the source code, builds up an internal representation of the program, then emits code in a target language.  The key difference between a normal compiler and a cross-compiler, though, is that a normal compiler usually outputs assembly (or some sort of bytecode), while a cross-compiler usually outputs constructs in a different programming language.

If you want to learn more about the key techniques involved in building such translators, you might want to read up on general compiler construction techniques.  It's really cool!

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's also possible to translate one language into several others using a single [pivot language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_language).